# Powershell Script Assistance

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a script that will query domain controllers to get the expiry date for passwords which works great.   I have an issue where I can't access a domain controller directly to run this same query as the only way I can access this domain is via a VPN and a Jumpbox.

What I would like to do is just create a simple script that could access a textfile.  Inside this file I'd like to have just a number to represent days since last password reset.   Each day this number would decrease.  Once the number inside the file was below a certain point I could have an email sent out.  I'm just not sure how I can do the process for having the file and decreasing the number each day inside the file.   I'd also need to reset it once it reached zero of course.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text file will save values as string. So you would have to type cast it to integer before you can do operations.

```
$File = "C:\temp\ADpasspolicy.txt"
[int]$PassPolicyVal = Get-Content -Path $File

#check for threshold value
if (!($PassPolicyVal -gt 10))
{
    #send mail
    Send-MailMessage -Subject "Password expired" -To "jane.doe@gmail.com" -From "John@gmail.com" -SmtpServer "smtpserveraddress" -Body "add body here"
}

if ($PassPolicyVal -le 0)
{
    $PassPolicyVal = 90
}
else
{
    #Decrement by 1 if greater than 0
    $PassPolicyVal--
}

$PassPolicyVal | Out-File -FilePath $File
```

Comment: I just had to alter the line

if ($PassPolicyVal -le 0)

as this was resetting the file to be 90 each time it ran.   But other then this I can make this work for my needs.   Appreciate the help.  :)

Comment: Rohin,

When I run this script within powershell the file will decrement ok.  When I try to run this outside of powershell it does not  decrment correctly.   Inside powershell it does throw and error on this line - [integer]$PassPolicyVal = Get-Content -Path $File    I'm thinking this is why it is not working outside, it is not liking the integer variable declaration?

Comment: @SteveWalsh Ah yes. I had not reallytested the script. it should be `[int]` instead of `[integer]`. Now it should be working as expected, including the `if ($PassPolicyVal -le 0)` loop.